# General solution to $\frac{d^{2}y}{dt^{2}}+f(t)y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a simple method to find the general solution to the ODE:
$$\frac{d^{2}y}{dt^{2}}+f(t)y=0\ .$$
Assume all the usual nice things about $f(t)$ like continuity and smoothness.

Comment: Can $f(t)$ be a linear function?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner $f(t)$ is not necessarily linear.

Comment: Expanding taylor series you can get some general expression. (if $f(t)$ continous everywhere then all points are regular).
Moreover, you can use the theory of WKB to estimate the behaviour near infinity.

Comment: In view of the oscillatory solutions for constant $f$, one more or less natural approach is to consider $y(t)=c\cdot\mathrm{exp}\left( \int^t \phi(\tau)^s \,{\mathrm d} \tau\right)$, which will get you down to a (still nonlinear, but first order) equation. E.g. for $s=1$, reduce it to $\phi'(t)+\phi(t)^2 = - f(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d^{2}y}{dt^{2}}+f(t)y=0\implies \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)+f(t)y=0$$
Integrating with respect to $~t~$,
$$\frac{dy}{dt}+\int f(t)y~dt=c\implies \frac{dy}{dt}+k(t)=c\qquad $$where $~c~$ is constant$~~$and we take $k(t)=\int f(t)y~dt$.

Again integrating with respect to $~t~$,
$$y(t)+\int k(t) ~dt =ct+d$$where $~c,~d~$ are constants.

---

or

---

$$\frac{d^{2}y}{dt^{2}}+f(t)y=0$$
Multiplying both side by $~2~\frac{dy}{dt}~$ we have,
$$~2~\frac{dy}{dt}~\frac{d^{2}y}{dt^{2}}+~2~f(t)~y~\frac{dy}{dt}=0$$
$$\implies \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2+f(t) \frac{d}{dt}(y^2)=0$$

Comment: Can you please explain why either of these methods is a "solution"? It seems to me that you have simply rewritten the original equation in a slightly different form.

Comment: You can't get a general solution, that form what you want, if your $~f(t)~$is not specified. Try those methods with a given $~f(t)~$, I am sure you will get your known form.